# UITableView with cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cocos2d-iphone

I am a learner in the area of Objective-C. I'm trying to build an iPhone app with cocos2d. Now I would like to use a UITableView to show data from an XML file.

Is it possible to use UITableView with cocos2d and is it also possible to retrive data from an XML file?

Answer (score 2):

You can very easily integrate `UIViews` with cocos2d scene by using `CCUIViewWrapper` class which was made by someone and posted on [cocos2d forum](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6889). I had used it and it is pretty simple to use everything is there on the forum.

And for XML parsing it's better if you use the parser provided by iOS as Jonathan said cocos2d is a game engine which doesn't provide any mechanism to parse XML files.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely!  The XML file doesn't even have to be local in your app.

I recommend parsing the XML with something like [TouchXML](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchXML).  The only built in iPhone XML parsing library is a event based one that is hard to use unless you have the right sort of structure in you data.

Then in the table view methods that fill your table with data, select items from the variables that you have parsed out of the data file.

Comment: Actually, libxml2 comes with iOS, and is very flexible... (DOM, SAX, HTML, XHTML, you name it, libxml2 can parse it).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Squeegy is right. I do want to correct a conceptual misunderstanding you appear to have, though. Any iPhone application you write will always be based on the core iPhone APIs. Thus, your using Cocos2d is irrelevant to your use of UITableView. As for XML parsing, that is, of course, not done by Cocos2d. Cocos2d is a high-level abstraction of OpenGL for relatively easy game development; XML parsing is not in its purview. Thus, again, your use of Cocos2d is irrelevant to your use of an XML parsing library.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use UITableView objects, UINavigationViewControllers etc alongside your Cocos2D app.

Just create a UIViewController in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and add it's view to the window.

Hold onto the EAGLView* Cocos2D uses, and switch between this OpenGL view and your view controller (with it's table views, buttons, and what have you).

If you want to display a table simultaneously with your Cocos2d content, it might be best to use the UI elements they provide.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the possibility of using cocos2d extensions. These are pretty much some `UIKit` classes rewritten in cocos2d.

Here is a [link](https://github.com/porumbes/Cocos2D-Extensions) I found with scroll and table views.
There isn't much explanation on how to use it, but it doesn't differ too much from `UIScrollView` and `UITableView`.